# SED regex-replace of a Log File

Tags: regex, sed

I run a minecraft server and like to periodically clean up my log files.  I've developed a bunch of regex commands that I am able to use in gedit or notepad++, and they work perfectly, but I'd like to be able to automate the process.

The essential file-cleaning command would look like this:

```
cat server.log | sed -e 's/REGEXTODELETE//g' > server.log
```

but I'm having trouble getting the regex commands to translate properly to SED.  I'm using sed on a CentOS6.3 box.

Here's an example of a command that works in notepad++:

```
^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ \[INFO\] Connection reset$
```

But when I enter it into my bash script:

```
cat server.clean.log | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* \[INFO\] Connection reset$//g' > server.clean.log
```

it empties the whole file.  I've looked all over, and I suspect I'm having an issue with whitespace, but after about an hour of searching I'm stuck.  Any help is appreciated, and I can provide more examples.

Comment: `cat file | anycmd > file` will truncate the file.  The shell truncates the file with `>` before cat ever sees the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting the input file before it is being read.

```
cat server.clean.log | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* \[INFO\]  Connection reset$//g' > server.clean.log
```

Should be something like

```
cat server.log | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* \[INFO\]  Connection reset$//g' > server.clean.log
```

In general,

```
program <infile >infile
```

will not work (reliably) since `infile` will get truncated before `program` gets a chance to read it

Comment: Blame my cat for stepping on my desk. I've removed the downvote.  Ironically, however, you're still recommending unnecessary use of `cat`.

Comment: Oh good. I thought I missed something. Re. UUoCat: I'm not. I'm just not getting into any side paths :)

Comment: Simply, `< server.log sed ...`

Comment: It's better than UUOC IMO, and still shows (easily) which file is being read as input.

Comment: This was such a dumb error on my part, thanks so much.

I have a follow up question though...in Notepad++ I get lines like this:

    [0;39m[32;1mSnailsAttack[0;39m:[37;1m OH[m

how do I strip that out, and while it doesn't show here, I have a giant "ESC" character before any of the ['s.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify a file in-line, without creating temporary files, you can use sed's `-i` option.  For example, if you want to remove any lines that have the string you've mentioned, you could use:

```
sed -i'' '/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* \[INFO\]  Connection reset$/d' server.log
```

This avoids unnecessary pipes, as well as the confusion you're experiencing with redirecting output to your input file.

Note that I'm using sed to DELETE LINES here.  When you use the `s/RE/text/` notation, you're replacing content IN-LINE.  Your total number of output lines will be the same as input, only (I gather) you'll have a bunch of *blank* lines if you just substitute the text to blanks.

If you don't mind dealing with the temporary file issue, you can probably get away with using `grep` instead of `sed` to make this a little more clear.

```
grep -v '^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* \[INFO\]  Connection reset$' server.log > clean..log
```

Or perhaps even:

```
grep -Pv '^\d+(-\d+)+ \d+(:\d+)+ \[INFO\]  Connection reset$' server.log > clean.log
```

if you're using Linux and don't mind having [evil regular expressions](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).  (In my experience, the `\d` POSIX class short-hand doesn't work reliably except when you're treating regexps as PCRE.